# Using expressions to get intellisense support in C#

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I'm trying use expressions in order to have strong typing over properties.

So I have this model.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this method which should, well in the end I would like to use the properties in some way but for now I just want to return them.

```
public List<string> DoSomething<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
{  
        List<string> props = new List<string>();

        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

            var q = memberExpression.Member.Name;

            props.Add(q);
        }
        return props;
}
```

This is the usage

```
var props = DoSomething<Entity>(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

Well, It works but only partially. What I mean by that is that it will work for reference types, for example it will work for Name property because it is a reference type, but it will return null for any value type, in this case for ID which is an int.

Why is that and what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` is an Expression that builds a Func which returns an `object` (which is a reference type).
If you pass `x => x.Id` as value of that Expression, the return type of the resulting Func will not match, as `int` is a value type but the Func is expected to return a reference type.

C#'s compiler will see that and automatically build a Func that wraps the `int` inside an `object` (called boxing). But that Func no longer has a simple MemberExpression as its body, because the MemberExpression has to be wrapped in a "boxing expression".

That's basically what happens. So you have to handle the case where `expression.Body` is not of type `MemberExpression` to fix that.

This is untested, but it might help:

```
if (!(expression.Body is MemberExpression))
{
    if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression && unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.TypeAs)
        expression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
    else
        expression = null;
    if (expression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("something happened");
}
```